# Regex matches in Java

Tags: c#, java, regex, match

I'm fairly new to Java, I'm trying to go over more advanced topics such as Regex.

What would be the Java equivillant to the following C# code:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, output)))
    {
...
    }
```

I'm kinda stuck. :/

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    ...
}
```